# How do I filter out certain events from Behavior Flow reports in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track a certain group of events related to purchasing on my website.

It would be the best option for me to use [Behavior Flow Report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=en) to analyze the event flow.

But, since there are a whole lot of events being tracked on my website, analyzing **Behavior Flow** report isn't that easy, since it includes other events not related to purchasing.

Is there a way to filter out certain events from this report, so that the report only shows sequences of chosen events (say, filtering by category).

Comment: This should be posted to Webmasters instead as it's not about coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since nobody could answer the question, there's a reasonable solution I've found: you just have to create a separate view for your account, then go the "filter" settings under the view you created and create a filter that excludes all hits with the event category you don't want to see in the event flow report.

[image: Example filter configuration]

You can also set up a filter to only include hits of a certain type.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a segment that contains the particular event category you're looking for.

In the Behavior Flow report, click "Add Segment" (at the top), then click "New Segment". Go down to "Conditions" and change the dropdown to "Event Category". From there, just add the criteria you want, name the segment, and then select it from the Segment area.

Now your Behavior Flow (and all other reports) are filtered by that segment based on your event category.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that it will include all users who triggered that event? Which means, it will also include all other triggered events by that user as long as the event is question was triggered.

Comment: THANK YOU NOW I WONT MAKE A CUSTOM CONVERSION FUNNEL I LOVE YOU